# Symfony2 Assetic - how to set different directories for assets in dev and prod env?

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm using assetic for compiling `.less` files, and managing assest in general. In dev environment I'm using less compiling via controller.

To keep my repository clean I've set `write_to` option in assetic configuration to some directory and set it as ignored by git. In dev it works as expected.

In prod env there is a problem though. Assets are dumping correctly but to the directory set in `write_to` option. But links to the assets links to the main `/web` directory and breaks.

And here is my question: how to use assetic for assets management to make it working in prod and keep it clean in repository.

Of course I can not commit dev generated assets to git, but it must break at some time.

Here is my assetic config:

## Assetic Configuration

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    write_to: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/assets/assetic"
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        less:
            node: '%node_path%'
            node_paths: ['%node_modules_path%']
            apply_to: '\.less$'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that was easy :)

I forgot that there is `config.yml` **and** `config_dev.yml`, so you can configure anything properly for dev, prod, test and whatever environment.

So it was enough to move line

```
write_to: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/assets/assetic"
```

from `config.yml` to `config_dev.yml`.

Now in dev env assets are generated to ignored by git dir, and in prod it is generated in `/web/` dir and linked properly.

Comment: Will do, but I have to wait 2 days :)